# Как передать 2D массив в GET запросе?

Tags: google-apps-script

Нужно передать 2D массив в GET запросе.
Массив преобразую в строку так:

```
   var params = JSON.stringify (SKU_ids_get)
   var apiconnection={'url':url,'key':apikey}
   var paramstring =''  
   for(var key in params) {  // преобразуем массив параметров в строку
      var value=params[key] 
      paramstring = paramstring + "&" + key + "=" + value 
    }
  paramstring = paramstring.substr(1) // убираем из строки первый знак конкотенации

  var url = apiconnection['url']+paramstring+"&key="+apiconnection['key'] //
```

`UrlFetchApp.fetch (url,{muteHttpExceptions: true})` - ругается, без массива все работает

Вот таким получается параметр url, на который ругается:

```
http://zapto.org/api/v1/update_sku_list?sku_ids=[["ПЖ214-1"],["ПЖ214-2"],["ПЖ214-4"]]&sku_vendor_info=[["ВХ",11,"Венеция","https://pravt/com/orders/"],[1,0,"",""],[3,0,"",""]]&key=12345
```

Насколько я понимаю, массив нужно сериализовать, аналогично php serialize. Но как это сделать в GAS?

Comment: Приведите пример кода. Вы больше половины не договариваете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С трудом нашел как решить задачу. Итак:

1. На стороне GAS:

   var params = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({"payment":{"0":"X","1":"Y"}}))
   url = "http://zapto.org/api/v1/update_sku_list?obj="+params
   UrlFetchApp.fetch (url,{muteHttpExceptions: true})
2. На стороне сервера PHP:

$payment = json_decode($_GET['params']['obj']['payment']);